# Testing: List index out of bounds in assert method

Tags: apex, unit-test, exception

I try to bugfix my test method which looks like this:

Util Class:

```
public static void createTestRecordsMultiple(Integer numAccts) {

    //Creation of parent Account
    Account parentmulti = new Account(Name='TestParentAccount2');
    insert parentmulti;

    //Creation of multiple Accounts and assignment to Parent Account
    List<Account> acctsmulti = new List<Account>();       
    for(Integer i=0;i<numAccts;i++) {
        Account am = new Account(Name='TestAccountMulti' + i, ParentId=parentmulti.Id, Variable__c=1000);
        acctsmulti.add(am);
    }
    insert acctsmulti;

    //Creation of Custom Object Record one for each Account created
    List<Object__c> multi = new List<Object__c>();
    //accts.clear();
    for (Integer j=0;j<numAccts;j++) {       
            multi.add(new Object__c(
                                //General
                                Account__c=multi[j].Id,
                                Variable2__c = true,
                                Varibale3__c = 1000
    ));}
    insert multi;
}
```

Test Class

```
static testMethod void runTestCases() { 

    TestUtil.createTestAdministrator();
    User u2 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Alias='sysadmin'];

    final Integer numAcctsMulti = 4;
    TestUtil.createTestRecordsMultiple(numAcctsMulti);

    //Run As U1
    System.RunAs(u2){

        list <Object__c> listcvl = [Select Variable__c, Variable2__c, Variable3__c FROM Object__c WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY and CreatedById = :u2.id];
        System.assertEquals(listcvl[1].Variable2__c, listcvl[0].Variable2__c, 'Variables are not equal');            

    }
}
```

I keep getting the below error message in the assert method:

> System.ListException: List index out of bounds

I have already debugged but do not really see the issue. It works with one record, but not with multiple...

Comment: Missing From in SOQL "list <Object__c> listcvl = [Select Variable__c, Variable2__c, Variable3__c WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY and CreatedById = :u2.id]; "  ?  From which object?

Comment: Apologies, I corrected. I did rephrase the original code, in the original code it was in...

Comment: You have to call your `createTestRecordsMultiple()` method inside the `System.RunAs()` method if you want the records to be inserted as your new user. Currently, if you select the objects created using this record, the query returns an empty list because they were created using your user. But the main question is: Why are you inserting the records using this new user?

Comment: Exactly i agree with @MartinLezer Answer.

Comment: I just tested, Martins answer works, great, thanks! I run with another user as it is recommended via SF testing best practices, to see how the code reacts with different access permissions.

Comment: It is interesting though that it worked with one record - I also did the record creation out of the runas statement...